# ICO image file with no specific dimension

Tags: icons, favicon

I have a Windows XP SP2. When I download ICO files from [this page](https://www.iconfinder.com/icons/118923/edit_paste_icon#size=128), they show no width and height properties. However, they all show the same file size: 108 KB, which is way too large for the site favicon I need. Why don't they have width and height and how can I reduce their file size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.ico is a container image file format that can contain multiple image files of different size.

It seems that whatever image size you choose on that page, you get the same .ico file with 64x64 pixels and below.

Even though browsers use 16x16 pixels for favicons, it's not a bad idea to use .ico files with larger images so that bookmarks dragged into the desktop still look good.

If you have enabled browser caching on your webserver, the favicon should only be downloaded once by your site's visitors.

If you want a smaller file, the easiest way would probably be to download a png version of the size you want and use one of the many png to ico converter webapps available on the web.